# Horizontal Partitioning in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, partitioning, large-data

I have a table with ~20 columns.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  GUID_PK  |  GUID_SET_ID  |  Col_3  |  Col_4  |  ... | Col_20
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

There could be thousands of `Sets` each having tens to less than a thousand records. Records within a set are all related to each other. sets are totally independent to each other. A whole set is read/written at a time in one big transaction. Once a record is written, it is read-only for ever, never altered, only read. Data is rarely deleted from this table. when it is deleted, the whole set is deleted in one go.

Only `SET_ID` is an incoming foreign key. `PK` is an outgoing foreign key to a different table. in the detail table about 3 or 4 records (each a single blob) are kept per master record.

Question is: should I partition the tables? I think *yes*. My boss thinks better. he wants the tables be created dynamically, one master one detail for each set. I personally am not comfortable with the dynamic creation idea, but fear the one-table-to-rule-them-all architecture.

The bulk insertions and bulk selects are definitely going to hit performance. Bulk deletes will again reorder the indexes. What would be an optimal structure?

Comment: when you insert the data all columns like `Col_x` are populated ? or just some?

Comment: @Stephan all columns are populated in one go. actually two columns are nullable and sometimes but rarely they may be null. but no record is updated later. what is done is done.

Comment: in this case you can partition the table by `GUID_SET_ID` using hash http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-hash.html

Comment: but hash partitions accept a fixed number of partitions to begin with. how do i determine that number? is there any decision parameter? an best practice?

Comment: it depends on the data volume you receive daily

Comment: have a look at the partitioning types ... maybe other type will suit you better : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html

Comment: @Stephan, could you please post your views as a short answer. your help has outgrown comments. this might be the answer i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the most of the `Col_x` columns are populated you can do a `HASH PARTITIONING` :

```
CREATE TABLE 

....

PARTITION BY HASH(GUID_SET_ID)
PARTITIONS NO_PART;
```

Where `NO_PART` is the number of partitions that you want , this should be established taking into account:

1) the volume of data you receive daily
2) the volume of data you estimate that will be received in the future

Also you can check other partition types [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html).